# VB.Net Extending Object IExtenderProvider

Tags: vb.net, winforms, iextenderprovider

Ok, I have been fighting this for a couple of days and I am at my wits end... I am trying to add a browsable property that is visible in the PropertyGrid during runtime by extending the Controls. No matter what I do, the iExtenderProvider doesn't appear to actually run.

The iExtenderProvider is located in a second project, and a reference was added to the main project. (code Below)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ControlArray
             Inherits Component
             Implements IExtenderProvider
    <Browsable(True)> Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
        Get
            Return 0
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function CanExtend(ByVal extendee As Object) As Boolean Implements IExtenderProvider.CanExtend
       Return TypeOf extendee Is Control
    End Function
End Class
```

I then build the second project, go back to the first project, and nothing in my properties window, I instantiate a control in the code and then try to find my "Count" property and there is nothing there. Any suggestions as to what could be the problem?

Comment: That is not exactly the right way to implement `IExtenderProvider` - some stuff is missing.  And `IExtenderProvider` work well with the VS IDE, but it wont with a PropertyGrid because that uses reflection to get the properties - you will need a TypeConverter

Comment: To clarify, the ExtenderProvider is used to add properties at design time in VS.  They are not real properties (see the syntax for adding Tooltip text).  For runtime you need a `TypeConverter` and a custom `PropertyDescriptor`.   These are a lot of boilerplate code and seems like a lot of work for a RO property.

Comment: Was only just a starting point... the end result was going to be in integration to be able to access a pseudo-name into the PropertyGrid so that the user can "Change the Control Name" during Runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before reading the answer**

Make sure you know:

An extender provider is a component that provides properties to other components. The property provided by the extender provider actually resides in the extender provider object itself and therefore is not a true property of the component it modifies.

**At design time,** the property appears in property window.

**At run time,** however, you cannot access the property through the component itself. Instead, you can call the getter and setter methods on the extender component.

**To implement an extender provider**

- Inherit from `Component` and implement the [`IExtenderProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx) interface.
- Decorate your component class with [`ProvideProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.providepropertyattribute.aspx) attribute and introduce provided property and the target control type.
- When implementing the [`CanExtend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.canextend.aspx) method, return true for each control type that you want to provide property for.
- Implement getter and setter methods for the provided properties.

**Learn More**

- [Extender Provider Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836.aspx)
- [IExtenderProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx)
- [How to: Implement a HelpLabel Extender Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229066.aspx)

**Example**

Using the below code you can implement an extender component `ControlExtender`. When you build the code and put an instance of `ControlExtender` on your the form, it extends all controls and add `SomeProperty on ControlExtender1` property for your controls in property grid.

1. Add a `Component` to the project and name it `ControlExtender`
2. Then use these codes in `ControlExtender.vb`

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<ProvideProperty("SomeProperty", GetType(Control))>
Public Class ControlExtender
    Inherits Component
    Implements IExtenderProvider
    Private controls As New Hashtable
    Public Function CanExtend(extendee As Object) As Boolean Implements IExtenderProvider.CanExtend
            Return TypeOf extendee Is Control
    End Function

    Public Function GetSomeProperty(control As Control) As String
        If controls.ContainsKey(control) Then
            Return DirectCast(controls(control), String)
        End If

        Return Nothing
    End Function
    Public Sub SetSomeProperty(control As Control, value As String)
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) Then
            controls.Remove(control)
        Else
            controls(control) = value
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note: You can also inherit `Control` based on your requirements. But in most cases inheriting a `Component` makes more sense.

Comment: I would at least *mention* that you can also inherit since that is how all the MSDN samples are (though inheriting from control seems odd),

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, seems that I am going to have to figure out how to add the new property to any control. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. There are many solutions for satisfying such general requirement. What's the real requirement?

Comment: Trying to generate a Visual Studio for my application I am working on. As it stands, I am able to add any control and then the PropertyGrid will display all of the properties, except for the Name property, and also won't display any of the Events.

Comment: If you want to create a real windows forms designer, you should change the way you are going. but if it's a simple custom designer I think you can show the name property using type descriptors or other mechanisms.

Comment: I tried this code for `DatagridViewTextboxColumn`, but it didn't show the property for the column, but displays for every other control, any ideas?

Comment: @Smith By default, extender provider properties are limited to show in the properties window of designer.

Comment: pay attention to capitalize G and S in `Get/Set` methods. It won't work in lower case

Comment: @IvanFerrerVilla Yes, nice! I can confirm it; however I may never write it as getSomething/setSomething, even in C#.